# how to set position of fragment in center in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

hi guys I was playing aroung with fragments in android.
I read that there are two ways to bind a fragment in an activity.
1)using `<fragment>` tag in layout(XML) file.
2)using FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction .
I want my Activity to handle fragment dynamically so i went for the 2nd approach.
But when a fragment is added it is added to left-top corner in RelativeLayout Activity(which appears to be the default behaviour of RelativeLayout)
I want my fragment to appear at center of the Activity Layout.
I just can't figure it out how to give position to fragmet in JAVA code.
I looked into stackoverflow also,

> > which uses --RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

which appears to work with View objects(Button,TextView etc).
Any suggestions.

Comment: Hard to say without looking at your code and your layout XML (hint: you might want to add those), but the trivial solution is to add a `FrameLayout` as the fragment container and use `layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `layout_centerVertical="true"` to position the `FrameLayout` inside the encapsulating `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a placeholder `FrameLayout` inside `RelativeLayout` in your XML and align it with `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`. Then replace this placeholder with your fragment in the code [FragmentTransaction#replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment))

In your Activity XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity class:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment, new MyFragment())
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity's layout use the attribute `android:layout_gravity="center"` for `RelativeLayout` in which `Fragment` resides. This will make all it's child element appear in center.